# how to use request with async module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sails.js

One of my controller is doing a crawl of 100s of pages wherein its extracting all the links from the page and when the links after saved to the database, i'm using a afterCreate lifecycle callback (below is the code)

```
afterCreate: function(createdLink, next) {
        var request = require("request");
        var currentLink = config.apiUrl + "update/linkstatus?linkPath=" + createdLink.linkUrl; 
        request(currentLink, function(error, response, body) {                                                                        
            console.log("saved", body);
        });
        next();
    }
```

this triggers another controller which gets the status of each of those links; below is the code for this controller:

```
linkstatus: function(req, res) {
    var request = require("request");
    var currentLink = req.query.linkPath;
    request(currentLink, function(error, response, body) {
            if(error) {
                    console.log(error);
            }
            var thisStatusCode = response.statusCode;
            Link.update(
                    {linkUrl: currentLink}, {statusCode: thisStatusCode}
                    ).exec(function(err, updatedLink) {
                    res.status(200).send(updatedLink);
            });
    });
}
```

The issue is that after some calls, I start getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
    at Request._callback (/home/ubuntu/myapp/api/controllers/UpdateController.js:11
2:32)
    at self.callback (/home/ubuntu/myapp/node_modules/request/request.js:360:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Request.onRequestError (/home/ubuntu/myapp/node_modules/request/request.js:1
```

Assuming that the 'linkstatus' controller action that I've written is not done properly to handle getting status code responses from 1000s of links simultaneously and as per my understanding, I need to use async module and Promises to solve this but i'm having difficulty grabbing the concept of callback and Promises so would be fantastic to get input on this

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that your not guaranteed a response and in those cases where the requests fails inside of node you to check for that before moving forward.

```
linkstatus: function(req, res, next) {
    var request = require("request");
    var currentLink = req.query.linkPath;
    request(currentLink, function(error, response, body) {
            if(error || !response) {
                    console.log(error);
            }
            else {
                var thisStatusCode = response.statusCode;
                Link.update(
                    {linkUrl: currentLink}, {statusCode: thisStatusCode}
                    ).exec(function(err, updatedLink) {
                    res.status(200).send(updatedLink);
                });
           }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks Meeker, this makes a lot of sense although curious, isn't there a way wherein if something fails, the process can come back to it again after the successful requests are done?

Comment: You can use a try/catch in the code, or if use a column like updatedBy to show when it the links was last updated and re-run if its been more than X time